# Parse html with ajax json inside

Tags: python, json, screen-scraping, html-parsing, web-scraping

I have such files to parse (from scrapping) with Python:

```
some HTML and JS here...
SomeValue = 
{
     'calendar': [
     {       's0Date': new Date(2010, 9, 12),
             'values': [
                     { 's1Date': new Date(2010, 9, 17), 'price': 9900 },
                     { 's1Date': new Date(2010, 9, 18), 'price': 9900 },
                     { 's1Date': new Date(2010, 9, 19), 'price': 9900 },
                     { 's1Date': new Date(2010, 9, 20), 'price': 9900 },
                     { 's1Date': new Date(2010, 9, 21), 'price': 9900 },
                     { 's1Date': new Date(2010, 9, 22), 'price': 9900 },
                     { 's1Date': new Date(2010, 9, 23), 'price': 9900 }]
     },
     'data': [{
     index: 0,
     serviceClass: 'Economy',
     prices: [9900, 320.43, 253.27],
     eTicketing: true,
     segments: [{
             indexSegment: 0,
             stopsCount: 1,
             flights: [{
                     index: 0,

... and a lot of nested data and again HTML and JS...
```

I need to parse it and extract all json data. Now I use regex with cleaning all '\n' and '\t' and eval() function to convert it to Python dictionary.. I really don't like this solution, eval() especially. But I looked at BeautifulSoup and lxml, and didn't find something that will help to parse it.
Can you suggest something better than regex and eval() for this task?
Page example: http://codepaste.ru/3830/

Comment: Is all the JS enclosed in `<script>` tags? If so this shouldn't be difficult using http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html

Comment: yes, see page on http://codepaste.ru/3830/
Thanks, somehow I missed simple HTML parser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [aarrghhh no regex dont use regex no regex no no nooooooo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

---

Use the `json` module to handle JSON data:

```
import json
json.loads( <string> )
```

Use `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to handle parsing the html page:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup( <string> )
```

If you want specific help, you'll need to provide specific data e.g. the class of the tags in which this data is enclosed. You could `soup.findAll` the script tags, for instance, then strip some lines to get to the JSON, then feed that into `json.loads`.

Comment: I've used simplejson, it failed to load data. json.loads() worked perfectly. Thanks